# Is it possible to establish more than one bluetooth communication in android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have android application the scan a Bluetooth device around, and connect them to start exchanging text.

I want the application to establish a communication with each Bluetooth device in the surrounding area and send text to all of them at once.

Is that possible to have multiple communication in android ? and if you have any examples ?

Answer (score 1):

For sure it is possible. You are talking about Bluetooth BR/EDR (2.x, 3.0) or Bluetooth low energy(4.0)?

For Bluetooth BR/EDR, use the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) to get started.

1. Just do a SDP to find all devices in range that support your UUID. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices) is how.
2. Then connect to each of them using a RFCOMM Connection [as a client](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAClient).

Obviously, the other devices should accept this connection. If those are Android as well, see the 'connecting as a server' [chapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAServer). (Basically it means waiting for a connection...).

For things not covered in the Android Official Documentation, see [this](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2010/11/android-bluetooth-rfcomm/).

You can also just take all paired devices, and try to connect to them(obviously only those in range will connect).